# What attitude or way of thinking should a good QA Tester possess?

Tags: learning

I am a new here and would like to learn tips from experienced QA Analysts. What do you think are the attitudes or qualities that will help me excel in this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reading [this blog post](http://testjutsu.com/2012/02/new-to-software-testing-read-this/) from Ben Kelly for an example

Continuous learning, critical thinking and good communication skills

or [this post](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/764) from James Bach

Comment: I would also like to add this post http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-key-properties-of-great-qa-team-member/.